# Apache: How to switch to CGI/FastCGI Server API?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I've installed the `mod_fastcgi` on my Apache and put LoadModule into my `httpd.conf` file.

When I do a `phpinfo()`, `mod_fastcgi` is in the loaded modules section, but the server API still shows up as Apache 2.0.

How do I change this?

Comment: Also see http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10

Answer (score 3):

Do the steps below:

- Disable the `php.conf` file that is configured to run as Apache module:

```
    # mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf.module
```

- Create the `php.fcgi` file in `/var/www/cgi-bin` with something like
  this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PHP_CGI=/usr/bin/php-cgi
    exec $PHP_CGI
```

- Modify the `DocumentRoot` or `VirtualHost` section to add the `AddHandler` and
  `Action` directive:

```
    ...
    AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
    Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
    ...
```

Testing with phpinfo():

```
# lynx -dump http://localhost/info.php | grep 'Server API'
   Server API CGI/FastCGI
```

Comment: Does this mean a server can only serve up mod_php *or* fastcgi, but not both? Or is there a way to run both?

Comment: Does `Server API CGI/FastCGI` mean that PHP runs using FastCGI or just CGI?