# How to switch from CGI/FastCGI Server API to DSO?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, cgi, suphp, dso

Apache: How to switch from CGI/FastCGI Server API to DSO?

I want to switch back and forth. I found this answer for the reverse step, but I need the the first part:

[Apache: How to switch to CGI/FastCGI Server API?](https://serverfault.com/questions/246743/apache-how-to-switch-to-cgi-fastcgi-server-api)

Actually I want to go back and froth between SuPHP (current)  --> DSO --> SuPHP in case this changes the link above.

Answer (score 1):

For switching to DSO (mod_php), you must have the php module enabled + the right handler activated, something like that:

```
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script  .php
```